# Keyboard type Issue with Appcelerator SDK 5.2.2GA in IPad Pro

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, xcode7.3

Keyboard shown for TextField in app build Appcelerator SDK 5.2.2GA in IPad Pro was not similar to TextField in app build with XCode 7.3. Can anyone let me know what to be done to bring keyboard same as xcode app?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So... what you consider different? Have you tried to style the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the keyboardType property on TextField in Titanium ??

If not, then please look into the various states of keyboards available in Titanium [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-keyboardType).

Titanium does not restrict you to choose the keyboards whatever are available in OS, and that's why you can set the **keyboardType** property of text-field according to your requirements.

I hope it clears your concern, if not then please provide us some more info.